# Executable jar run permanently

Tags: java, microservices

I am running an executable jar using the command prompt. But after command prompt closing the execution is stopped. I need to run this permanently. Because this is a microservice.
How can I achieve this goal
I am running using `java -jar JARPATH`

Comment: Which OS you are running on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several options:

**1) Creating a service as was mentioned in the first answer and comment.**

**2) Run a process in the background.**

```
nohup java -jar my-service.jar &
```

Where `nohup` command enables a process to continue running in the background when a user exits a shell.

To terminate the service, you need to kill the process.

You can create a `run-script` writing PID to a variable (or a text file):

```
#!/bin/bash
my-service &
export SERVICE_PID=$!
```

And kill the PID in `stop-script`:

```
#!/bin/bash
kill -9 $SERVICE_PID
```

**3) Run process in a container, e.g. Docker**

Running process in container allows has some advantages and allows to manage many different options rather than just 'run-and-stop'.

Answer (score 2):

Simply create a service to invoke jar file. Services can run indefinitely and can be triggered at startup or can be started or stopped manually.